# Error generated in netbeans generated code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

After looking everywhere, NOBODY has this same problem. I need to edit netbeans generated code because when I deleted a few Swing Components in design view a bug caused the variable declarations to be deleted but in initComponents() everywhere that those components were used is still there throwing an error and not allowing me to run the program, here is the code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controlpanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author Cam_2
 */
public class ControlPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ControlPanel
     */
    public ControlPanel() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        filler1 = new javax.swing.Box.Filler(new java.awt.Dimension(130, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(130, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(130, 32767));
        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jInternalFrame2 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        redLight = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        whiteLight = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        blueLight = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        greenLight = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        yellowLight = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jInternalFrame3 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jFormattedTextField2 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        jButton1.setText("Apply Changes");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jInternalFrame1.setTitle("Button Controller");
        jInternalFrame1.setToolTipText("Controls the buttons that normally activate the lights.");
        jInternalFrame1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(140, 160));
        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Button Activation");
        jLabel1.setToolTipText("Controls whether pressing a button will power the light or not");

        jButton2.setText("Enable");
        jButton2.setToolTipText("Controls whether pressing a button will power the light or not.");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Currently Disabled");
        jLabel2.setToolTipText("Controls whether pressing a button will power the light or not");
        jLabel2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        jCheckBox1.setText("Toggle Mode");
        jCheckBox1.setToolTipText("Controls whether pressing a button will toggle the light on rather than only powering the light while the button is held down.");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jCheckBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jInternalFrame2.setTitle("Light Controller");
        jInternalFrame2.setToolTipText("Controls all the LED lights.");
        jInternalFrame2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(140, 200));
        jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

        redLight.setText("Red Light");

        whiteLight.setText("White Light");

        blueLight.setText("Blue Light");

        greenLight.setText("Green Light");

        yellowLight.setText("Yellow Light");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame2.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame2Layout);
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(redLight)
                    .addComponent(yellowLight)
                    .addComponent(greenLight)
                    .addComponent(blueLight)
                    .addComponent(whiteLight))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(redLight)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(yellowLight)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(greenLight)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(blueLight)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(whiteLight)
                .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jInternalFrame3.setTitle("Screen Controller");
        jInternalFrame3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(140, 313));
        jInternalFrame3.setVisible(true);

        jButton3.setText("Toggle On");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("LED Char Screen");
        jLabel3.setToolTipText("Control whether the LED matrix is on or off.");
        jLabel3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(107, 16));

        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("Currently Off");

        jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel5.setText("Text To Display:");
        jLabel5.setToolTipText("The text shown on the LED screen.");

        jFormattedTextField1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        jFormattedTextField1.setToolTipText("Maximum characters is 20.");
        jFormattedTextField1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jFormattedTextField1FocusLost(evt);
            }
        });

        jFormattedTextField2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        jFormattedTextField2.setToolTipText("Maximum characters is 20.");
        jFormattedTextField2.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jFormattedTextField2FocusLost(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel6.setText("Line 1:");

        jLabel7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel7.setText("Line 2:");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame3.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame3.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame3Layout);
        jInternalFrame3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 53, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 105, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jInternalFrame3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(489, 489, 489))
        );

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 147, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 147, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 992, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(182, 182, 182)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 196, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jInternalFrame3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 309, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 287, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        javax.swing.JButton src = (javax.swing.JButton) evt.getSource();
        if(src.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Enable")) {
            jLabel2.setText("Currently Enabled");
            src.setText("Disable");
        } else {
            jLabel2.setText("Currently Disabled");
            src.setText("Enable");
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        javax.swing.JButton src = (javax.swing.JButton) evt.getSource();
        if(src.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Toggle On")) {
            jLabel4.setText("Currently On");
            src.setText("Toggle Off");
        } else {
            jLabel4.setText("Currently Off");
            src.setText("Toggle On");
        }
    }                                        

    private void jFormattedTextField1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                               
        JFormattedTextField src = jFormattedTextField1;
        String prevText = src.getText();
        if(prevText.length() > 20) {
            src.setText(prevText.substring(0, 19));
            final JDialog notice = new JDialog(cp, "Notice");
            notice.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
            notice.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            notice.setModal(true);
            notice.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            JTextArea noticeLabel = new JTextArea("What you entered into Line 1 of the LED Screen exceeded the maximum 20 characters. The message has been shortened from \"" + prevText + "\" to \""+ src.getText() +".\"");
            noticeLabel.setLineWrap(true);
            noticeLabel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            noticeLabel.setEditable(false);
            JButton okButton = new JButton("Okay");
            okButton.setSize(new Dimension(300, 120));
            noticeLabel.setSize(new Dimension(350, 60));
            noticeLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 18));
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    notice.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            notice.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            notice.add(noticeLabel);
            notice.add(okButton);
            notice.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                              

    private void jFormattedTextField2FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                               
        JFormattedTextField src = jFormattedTextField2;
        String prevText = src.getText();
        if(prevText.length() > 20) {
            src.setText(prevText.substring(0, 19));
            final JDialog notice = new JDialog(cp, "Notice");
            notice.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
            notice.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            notice.setModal(true);
            notice.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            JTextArea noticeLabel = new JTextArea("What you entered into Line 2 of the LED Screen exceeded the maximum 20 characters. The message has been shortened from \"" + prevText + "\" to \""+ src.getText() +".\"");
            noticeLabel.setLineWrap(true);
            noticeLabel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            noticeLabel.setEditable(false);
            JButton okButton = new JButton("Okay");
            okButton.setSize(new Dimension(300, 120));
            noticeLabel.setSize(new Dimension(350, 60));
            noticeLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 18));
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    notice.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            notice.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            notice.add(noticeLabel);
            notice.add(okButton);
            notice.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                              


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox blueLight;
    private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler1;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox greenLight;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame2;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox redLight;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox whiteLight;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox yellowLight;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static ControlPanel cp;

     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                cp = new ControlPanel();
                cp.setVisible(true);
                cp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

How would I be able to edit the generated code?

Comment: did you try cleaning and building the project after deletion of components or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If problem persist, you have to open your JFrame class in any text editor: Notepad, Notepad++, Wordpad, etc. and delete there your errors. Then go back to netbeans and reload your project.

To delete your form items use **Navigator** window (Ctl+7) and safely delete them.